# requests.exceptions.SSLError in scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the professor's name list.
However, when I run the code, the result show the error.
I searched for hours to find out the hint, but still, I'm stuck.

Here is my part of the code

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv



class Professors:

    def __init__ (self, csis_professor_id = ""):
        self.csis_professor_id = csis_professor_id

    def requestHeaders(self):
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

        return headers

    def CSIS_professor(self):

        csisProfessrs = []

        url = 'https://banserv2.douglas.bc.ca/prod/bwysched.p_course_search?wsea_code=CRED&term_code=202030&session_id=6772994&sel_subj=dummy&sel_camp=dummy&sel_sess=dummy&sel_attr=dummy&sel_levl=dummy&sel_schd=dummy&sel_ptrm=dummy&sel_insm=dummy&sel_link=dummy&sel_wait=dummy&sel_day=dummy&sel_begin_hh=dummy&sel_begin_mi=dummy&sel_begin_am_pm=dummy&sel_end_hh=dummy&sel_end_mi=dummy&sel_end_am_pm=dummy&sel_instruct=dummy&sel_open=dummy&sel_resd=dummy&sel_resd=R&sel_subj=CSIS&sel_number=&sel_camp=&sel_sess=&sel_day=m&sel_day=t&sel_day=w&sel_day=r&sel_day=f&sel_day=s&sel_day=u&sel_instruct='

        result = requests.get(url, headers = self.requestHeaders(), verify = False)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
        
        print(soup)



    
    @staticmethod
    def run():
        professors = Professors()
        professors.CSIS_professor()
```

and the error message appears like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    Professors.run()
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/douglas-api/scraper/src/professors/professors.py", line 41, in run
    professors.CSIS_professor()
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/douglas-api/scraper/src/professors/professors.py", line 29, in CSIS_professor
    result = requests.get(url, headers = self.requestHeaders(), verify = False)
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='banserv2.douglas.bc.ca', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /prod/bwysched.p_course_search?wsea_code=CRED&term_code=202030&session_id=6772994&sel_subj=dummy&sel_camp=dummy&sel_sess=dummy&sel_attr=dummy&sel_levl=dummy&sel_schd=dummy&sel_ptrm=dummy&sel_insm=dummy&sel_link=dummy&sel_wait=dummy&sel_day=dummy&sel_begin_hh=dummy&sel_begin_mi=dummy&sel_begin_am_pm=dummy&sel_end_hh=dummy&sel_end_mi=dummy&sel_end_am_pm=dummy&sel_instruct=dummy&sel_open=dummy&sel_resd=dummy&sel_resd=R&sel_subj=CSIS&sel_number=&sel_camp=&sel_sess=&sel_day=m&sel_day=t&sel_day=w&sel_day=r&sel_day=f&sel_day=s&sel_day=u&sel_instruct= (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:720)'),))
```

btw, I'm using python 3.5.3 Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The target site is too much slow that why it showing first ```MaxRetryError:``` then it coming ```SSLError``` . so when program trying to visit the link the ```requests``` lib getting timeout. That's why it showing the error. so you can use ```selenium``` . That @AaronS user already said in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what's going on with this website. It's relatively basic in terms of design. It takes a huge time getting the source HTML which I suspect there's some browser authentication which I'm not privy to. I tried with specific headers and params without success. Requests also has a feature where you don't have to verify the SSL handshake which was still outputting the error.

That being said, using selenium can grab the data you require.

Selenium is a python package that automates browser activity, primarily meant for automated testing rather than web scraping. It is usually a package of last resort if the datasets are huge. In this case the dataset isn't.

### Code Example

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'c:\users\aaron\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
professors = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
for a in soup.select('table')[3].select('tr')[1:]:
    rows = a.select('td:nth-child(13)')
    for a in rows:
        professors.append(a.get_text())
```

### Code Explanation

We import the webdriver module from selenium. This ensures a secure connection between the our code for browser activity and chromedriver. You will need to download chromedriver from the website [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/)

We then direct the webdriver to chromedriver so that we can instigate browser activity. In this case we're using chrome but you could use other browsers if you prefer.

The `executable_path` is just wherever we have our chromedriver.

The `get()` method of driver takes the browser to that website of our choice and simulates loading the page.

`driver.page_source` grabs the HTML once the page has loaded. We can use this with BeautifulSoup to parse the page.

Now there are several tables on this webpage. The table we want is the fourth one so `select('table')[3]`. We also want to select the second row of this table onward (they haven't properly formatted the table correctly) Hence the `select('tr')[1:]` part. This gives us a list that we can loop around.

The select method allows us to use CSS selectors, here because we're having to use a specific table of many and to specify from which row to take it the codes abit more cumbersome. So we now have a list of the rows of the table, we need to loop around this.

In every row of the table, it's the 13th column that has the professors names. So we want to select that for every row, which is what we do with `a.select('td:nth-child(13)')`

This gives us a list of all the professors HTML tags and text. We then use the `get_text()` method to grab the text and we add this to a list called `professors`.

### Additional Information

In general grabbing table data from HTML is cumbersome with beautifulsoup. In this case because I was unable to make a HTTP request without simulating browser activity, I was unable to use pandas.

Pandas is a package that can handle html tables very well using the pandas.read_html(url) method. You can put the url of choice of a website and will churn out the table in a format. Doesn't always get it right but it's always the most concise way to get table data.

### Code Tips

I'm not sure whether your intention was to learn making classes etc.. but for such a small script it's unlikely classes or even functions are that useful to you. They're great for larger scripts and when you need to share lots of variables between functions.

Functions should only contain one function if possible, and certainly if you're just storing a variable or it's just one line of code in a function, it's likely that the function you're creating is not worth creating.

For example you've created a headers function called `requestHeaders` which just has a string in it. It would be worth just making a class variable for this that can be called upon in subsequent functions, if you were hell bent on making a class for this.

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful. Acutally, I tried to fird another way withouth Selenium, but as you said, the Selenium is only way to get that data :)